# RoR: The right way of rescuing a DB exception on save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've recently faced the problem of my DB failing with `Adaptive Server connection timed out` quite often after I try to save an ActiveRecord model.

If I try to `rescue` this failed attempt and save the object again I get `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError`, so I have to recreate the object being saved from the very beginning which may be quite an expensive procedure.

What is the right way of handling this situation on the app side given that I cannot affect DB performance in any way?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError` is sent when there is optimistic locking in place. Are you sure there is no attempt to modify the record in parallel?

Comment: @NicNilov, yes, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

reload is what you want

```
begin
  object.save
rescue
  object.reload.save
end
```

something like that. here are the docs for it:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload

Comment: Well, that's what I wrote about. Once I reload, I get the object in a state that was persisted to DB before I made any changes to it, so I have to go through the whole process again and this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Okay for some reason it wasn't clear to me that you had tried just a basic reload or that this particular fix was undesirable. Also it's not clear in your question why it's expensive to recreate the object or why you have to recreate the object in memory from scratch at all.

Comment: well, it is expensive to recreate not the object itself, but its new state cause it requires some rather heavy calculation and network interaction. I might be caching the results to some other place before applying them to the model, but this looks more like a workaround than a solution to me. I want to know how to deal with this in an `ActiveRecord` way )

Comment: ActiveRecord isn't going to be able to help you here. It sounds like you've got some database performance issues that need to be solved by someone with an index or something. You can also try making the active record object less complex. Or finally, you can cache like you said. Save the attributes to a variable and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

The `Adaptive Server connection timed out` error is due to update of the record taking too long. One way to handle that is to increase the statement timeout in `database.yml`:

```
timeout: 10000 # milliseconds, default is 5000
```

This does not address the question directly but might help to lower the frequency of the issue.

As described in [Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#optimistic-locking), optimistic locking only works when the `lock_version` field is present in the table. It is not clear whether you need the locking in the first place, but your Rails clearly does have it enabled and working.

As the value of `lock_version` is the only thing that triggers the `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError`, you could manipulate that on your second saving attempt. The straightforward way would be to query the latest value from the database and update your object accordingly:

```
lock_version = Model.where(id: model.id).pluck(:lock_version).first
model.lock_version = lock_version

# then attempt to save again

model.save!
```

Note that this will rewrite the database state with your changes regardless of any modification made in parallel, defeating the purpose of locking.

Having said that, it's a bit fishy that `locking_version` changes when the update times out. It certainly worth digging into it to see why exactly that happens. At the very least you should be sure to wrap the update in a transaction, that alone may fix the issue.